# Droppable element preference (fixed navbar)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have fixed bs4 navbar and bunch of divs under that. All of these divs including navbar are droppable, because of dragging element between these divs and navbar. I would like to give preference to navbar if element is dragged from div.

**Let me try to explain by example:**

Let's drag element from navbar, scroll down a bit and then drag element back to the navbar. Element will drop to the div under the navbar instead of navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav">           
    <div id="launchPad" class="pull-right">
       <div id="zarazka" style="cursor:move; z-index:1031;">
          <h6 class="h5">Zarážka</h6>          
       </div>
    </div>
</nav>     
<div id="zpravy" class="pb-3">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="zprava" id="1">asdasd</div></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="zprava" id="2">asdasd</div></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="zprava" id="3">asdasd</div></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="zprava" id="4">asdasd</div></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="zprava" id="5">asdasd</div></div></div>
</div>

$("nav").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    addClasses: false,                                                    
    drop: function(event, ui) { $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable)); }
}); 

$("#zpravy .row").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    addClasses: false,
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).after($(ui.draggable));        
    }
});

$("#zarazka").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",
    opacity: 0.5,
    zIndex: 1031,
    scroll:false,
    containment: "body"   
});
```

Comment: It's not clear the logic here. After you drag it down, do you want the user to drag it back to remove the item? Why not a delete button? If they do need to drag it back to the start, I think you need to increase the helpers `z-index` or check the `stack` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the issue the offset. When the document has been scrolled down, the draggable is landing outside of the droppable position. You can trick it by looking at the offset position, if the drag is offset 50px or less, then append it to the `nav`.

```js
$(function() {
  var over = false;

  $(".navbar").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    addClasses: false,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("Nav Drop: Append Drag to LaunchPad.");
      $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });

  $("#zpravy .row").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    addClasses: false,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if (over) {
        console.log("Row Drop: Append Drag to LaunchPad.");
        ui.draggable.appendTo($("#launchPad"));
      } else {
        console.log("Row Drop: Append Drag after this.");
        $(this).after($(ui.draggable));
      }
    }
  });

  $("#zarazka").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",
    opacity: 0.5,
    zIndex: 1032,
    scroll: false,
    containment: "body",
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      if (e.clientY < 50) {
        console.log("drag: Over set to true");
        over = true;
      } else {
        over = false;
      }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      if (e.clientY < 50) {
        console.log("dragstop: Over set to true");
        over = true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1031;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.row {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js
"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div id="launchPad" class="pull-right">
    <div id="zarazka" style="cursor:move; z-index:1031;">
      <h6 class="h5">Zarážka</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="main-content">
  <div id="zpravy" class="pb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="2">Nullam ornare ex ac sem tempus, sit amet facilisis lacus rhoncus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="3">Nullam ornare ex ac sem tempus, sit amet facilisis lacus rhoncus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="4">Sed volutpat nulla a iaculis dignissim.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="5">Curabitur interdum mauris at elit semper commodo.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe not the best solution, yet it till help. The better solution, based on some research, is not to use a fixed position. You can look at doing a few other things, but they are all going to be tricks to get the drag item to append to the row or the navbar based on where the item is dropped.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Twisty. It works and helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your `nav` is positioned as fixed, so it is always at the top of the page. When you are dragging your elements around there are actually a few `div` behind the `nav` and so when you drop something on what appears to be the `nav` its  being placed between the `div` lying behind it.

If you set a `height` for your `nav`, and wrap the rest of your content in a `div` with a `padding-top` that is equal to the `height` of the `nav` then there will not be anything behind the `nav` and the confusion will not occur.

As this is 'dead space' (it will always be hidden behind the `fixed` `nav`) you should do this regardless, as you will continue to lose content behind the `nav` if you do not.

I have wrapped the main content in a `<div class='main-content'></div>` and added the following CSS:

```
nav {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.main-content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you

---

## Demo

```js
$("nav").droppable({
  tolerance: "pointer",
  addClasses: false,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});

$("#zpravy .row").droppable({
  tolerance: "pointer",
  addClasses: false,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).after($(ui.draggable));
  }
});

$("#zarazka").draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: "invalid",
  opacity: 0.5,
  zIndex: 1031,
  scroll: false,
  containment: "body"
});
```

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js
"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav">
  <div class="logo">

  </div>
  <div id="launchPad" class="pull-right">
    <div id="zarazka" style="cursor:move; z-index:1031;">
      <h6 class="h5">Zarážka</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="main-content">

  <div id="zpravy" class="pb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="1">asdasd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="2">asdasd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="3">asdasd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="4">asdasd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="zprava" id="5">asdasd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, but this does not work. The solution above works.